# Можно ли представить операции rotr и shr арифметически?

Tags: математика, логика

Существует ли способ представления побитовых операций **rotr** и **shr** в виде арифметических действий (+, -, *, /, ** и т.д.)?

Comment: Ну с shr все просто. целочисленное деление на 2. Вот с ror сложнее, нужно получить остаток от деления. И если операция получения остатка от деления есть то что то типа поделить на 2 и прибавить остаток от деления умноженный на 2 в степени - размер операнда (т.е. 2^8 для байта)

Comment: @Mike: Может, оформите как ответ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

shr это целочисленное деление на 2.

Вот с ror сложнее, нужно получить остаток от деления. И если операция получения остатка от деления есть, то ror на 1 бит равен X/2 плюс остаток от деления умноженный на 2 в степени - размер операнда (т.е. 2^8 для байта)

Comment: А я смотрю на rotr и думаю "это про [ротор](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80_(%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0)) так что ли?"

Comment: @LEQADA это про "вращение" байта вправо, когда все разряды сдвигаются (вправо, ясное дело), а самый младший становится самым старшим

Comment: @gbg да, я понял после ответа Mike )